# rake assets:precompile broke my app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

I'm having problems with some site functions after running `rake assets:precompile`.  My dropdown menu stopped working, and my `create.js` jQuery is adding two objects when only one should be created.

I duplicated the issue by downloading the code to a new environment, testing that everything worked fine, and then precompiling again.  Sure enough it started the same issues.

I tried running `rm -fr public/assets`, `rake assets:clean`, and `rake assets:clobber`, none of which did anything.  The problems don't have error codes associated with them in server outputs or the browser, so I have no idea how to troubleshoot further.

Any ideas on what may have happened, and how I can fix it?

Also, can I push new code in other areas to my Heroku app without worrying about the issues occurring on the live server, as long as I don't precompile?

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require jquery.remotipart
```

Comment: So is `public/assets` now empty?

Comment: Yes, the folder was deleted at some point while trying those commands

Comment: If you are running the server in production mode, make sure you require js files in right dependency order in your `application.js`.

Comment: @YaroHoloduke I added my application.js above.  I'm not sure what the right dependency order is, could you look at it?

Comment: @Virge, try removing `require_tree .` and mimic its function - write `require ...` for all your js files until everything works as expected in development. At this point you will have the application.js that will be interpreted the same way in production. I'm not sure why Rails does this, but in development assets are loaded by dependence, and in production in some other order.

Comment: Removing that worked! Thanks so much, this has been an issue for days.